# How to do android payments using facebook credits

Tags: android

I just want to do payment in android using facebook gateway.Is it possible in android native app.?if it possible means, how could i do tht?
  I've searched over tht "http://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/".But i donno we can implement it on android or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=172290966189492

> Can Facebook Credits be used in native iOS and Android apps?
>
> Facebook Credits on mobile does not support native iOS or Android
>   apps. Facebook Credits are available for use in mobile browser-based
>   web apps. We ask that developers check the terms of service and
>   payment guidelines for the host platform in order to ensure
>   compliance. Permalink ·

Comment: I've done all my app credit enabled.Refered:"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/build/".After that how could i integrate fb credit with my android web app.I dont see any sample code.Only JS files are available.Any android integrate code available?

Comment: thanks.. But how could i call this API from my android app.??